# Why can't beautifulsoup detect this table from this website?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to webscrape the table from this website "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Jockey/JockeyRanking.aspx" onto an excel sheet with beautifulsoup and pandas. This is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Send a GET request to the URL
url = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Jockey/JockeyRanking.aspx"
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find the table element and extract the data
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "table_bd "})
if table is None:
    print("Table not found.")
else:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    # Save the data to an Excel spreadsheet
    df.to_excel("hkjc.xlsx", index=False)
```

For some reason, It prints "table not found", but there is clearly a table on this website.

Can someone let me know why this is happening please, and how the code can be changed for this issue to be fixed?

Comment: From my experience, the table is may be loaded dynamically via JavaScript, you are scraping the raw HTML instead of the fully loaded version. I suggest using selenium to wait for the page to fully load before scraping the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use playwright to scrape the content since requests won't be enough to get the table data. The HTML parsing can still be handled by the BeautifulSoup though.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

url = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Jockey/JockeyRanking.aspx"

with sync_playwright() as pw:
    browser = pw.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(url, wait_until="networkidle")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content(), "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one(".table_bd")

    if table is None:
        print("Table not found.")
    else:
        df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
        # Save the data to an Excel spreadsheet
        df.to_excel("hkjc.xlsx", index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked really well! Follow-up question: is there any way I can print out a table from another website onto another sheet of the excel?

Comment: You're welcome! Please create a new question and include relevant code snippets along with a detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Just created the new question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the fact that the class name of the table you are trying to extract is "table_bd " with a trailing space. Try removing the trailing space in your find method

Like so

```
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "table_bd"})
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a good find. However, it still says "table is not found". There seems to be another issue.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, you can try using the developer tools in your web browser to inspect the HTML code of the website and make sure that the class name of the table you want to extract is indeed "table_bd" or if there are any other issues.
And, make sure that the requests module is imported at the beginning of your script

Comment: Sorry I checked, I'm definitely sure its "table_bd". The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: In that case, it's possible that the website is using JavaScript to load the table dynamically, and the requests module does not execute JavaScript. As a result, the html content returned by requests.get() might not include the table you're looking for

You can try using a headless web browser like Selenium to simulate a real user interacting with the website, which will allow you to access the fully rendered HTML content, including any content generated by JavaScript